# How to export a Table's schema to another Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 10 tables in my database. Out of this I want to generate 5 tables with same structure and dependencies in a different database. I don't need to copy the data inside these tables, just the schema of tables. How do I do this? I don't want to manually copy the code but to generate files to export.

Comment: Are the tables all in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, SQL-Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are copying from database(Schema) in `SQL Server` to another, then what you can do is use the `Tasks>Generate Scripts`

[image]

From here you press the `Select Specific Database Objects` and select the tables in the `tables` section that you want to carry to your new database.

[image]

Then go to the `Set Scripting Options` Menu, and press the `advanced` button at the top right of that menu. Another menu will pop up with options. Based on what you said the default (following) options should work.

[image]

Then Just Generate it in your desired format and make sure you're pointing them all to the correct database!

Comment: Just note that even though the process is similar the wizard used in the 2008 version has different steps and options. The idea is correct though.

Comment: Per jps's comment and sake of documentation these images are from SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server Management Studio you can right-click on the database in the Object Explorer and choose `Tasks/Generate Scripts`and follow the instructions in the wizard.